# Rickshaw JS axis render issue when called within AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, ajax, axes, rickshaw

I am creating a graph using Rickshaw JS. To do this i have created a function  which when called renders the graph. 
The issue i am facing is when called within the script tags, the function renders everything fine, as i expect. However when called from within the success function of an AJAX call, the axes do not show up.

Relevant code snippet:

```
<script>
function ProbabilityPlot(a) {
    var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
       ...
    });
    graph.render();

    var xAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
       ...
    });
    xAxis.render();

    var yAxis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y({
       ...
    });
    yAxis.render();
};

$.ajax({
    url: plotURl,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        ProbabilityPlot([ {{plot_data}} ]); <-- axes do NOT work
    }
});

ProbabilityPlot([ {{plot_data}} ]); <-- eveything works perfectly
</script>
```

I can verify that the parameters passed onto the function are same in both cases.

Comment: What's the point of `.bind(this)` in your code? There is nothing you bind your callback functions to. Also your braces are not matched. Fix the indentation of your code, match your braces and explain what you expect `this` to point to in your callbacks.

Comment: Currently i get static data which is represented by _{{plot_data}}_. Now i am switching to AJAX to get asynchronous data. I was using bind(this) to attach this function to a DOM element of graph that i create. I have updated the code in the question further.

Comment: I have removed _bind(this)_ from the original snippet as i feel that it is irrelevant to the issue i am facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about how it was fixed or what the underlying issue is, but the fix (atleast for now) was to move the scripts to the head of the html.

```
<script src="{% static "Home/js/vendor/jquery.js" %}"></script>
<script src="http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/vendor/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rickshaw/1.5.1/rickshaw.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Then the fix is to enclose your custom JS section in `$(document).ready(function () { /* ... */ });` - or, for short:`$(function () { /* ... */ });`

Comment: Perfect thank you!! Somehow missed it.. will add the check going forward.. thanks again!

Comment: With this you can move your libraries to the end of the document again of course.